# What are jftfdi jffi doing to my query string?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, jsf-2.2

We are using JavaServer Faces 2.2 (Mojarra 2.2.1) in our project. I noticed something odd. On a page called `reporting.xhtml` where I use `f:metadata` with the new `f:viewAction` my browser, Safari in this case, shows the following query string:

```
reporting.jsf?jftfdi=&jffi=reporting%3Ffaces-redirect%3Dtrue
```

What wizardry is this? What are the parameters jftfdi and jiffi doing? What is their purpose?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's part of the new JSF 2.2 feature as described by spec [issue 949](http://java.net/jira/browse/JAVASERVERFACES_SPEC_PUBLIC-949). Basically, it enables JSF to identify the client window. It's basically the same as `cid` in CDI's `@ConversationScoped` and `windowId` in CODI's `@ViewScoped`/`@ViewAccessScoped`. This client window ID is in turn used by among others the new JSF 2.2 `@FlowScoped` scope as described by spec [issue 730](https://java.net/jira/browse/JAVASERVERFACES_SPEC_PUBLIC-730).

The "What's new in JSF 2.2?" article of my fellow Arjan Tijms explains the need pretty clearly:

> ### LifeCycle
>
> #### Identify client windows via a Window Id
>
> Arguably one of the biggest problems that has been plaguing web application development since its inception is the inability to distinguish requests originating from different windows of a single browser. Not only has an actual solution been long overdue, it has taken a long time to realize this even was a problem.
>
> The root of the problem, as always, is that the HTTP protocol is inherently stateless while applications in general are not. There is the concept of a cookie though, which is overwhelmingly the mechanism used to distinguish requests from different users and to implement things like a session scope where on its turn the bulk of login mechanisms are based on.
>
> While a cookie does work for this, it’s global per browser and domain. If a user opens multiple tabs or windows for the same domain then requests from those will all send the same cookie to the server. Logging in as a different user in a different window for the same website is thus not normally possible, and having workflows (involving post-backs, navigation) in different windows can also be troublesome because of this.
>
> In JSF there are various solutions that are somehow related to this. The view scope effectively implements a session per window as long as the user stays on the same page and does only post-backs. The Flash is used for transferring data between different pages (presumably within the same window) when navigation is done via Redirect/GET. There’s a wide variety of scopes implemented by third parties that do something similar.
>
> All of these have some implicit notion or assumption of the concept of a ‘client window’, but there is no explicit API for this.
>
> JSF 2.2 will introduce support for two different aspects of this:
>
> - Identification of an individual window: the Client Window Id
> - API and life-cyle awareness of the window concept

Apparently you've configured your application as such.

#### See also:

- [What's new in JSF 2.2? - Lifecycle - Identify client windows via window Id](http://jdevelopment.nl/jsf-22/#949)
- [What's new in JSF 2.2? - Navigation - Faces Flow](http://jdevelopment.nl/jsf-22/#730)