# How to disable jftfdi jffi query params in JSF

Tags: jsf, mojarra, jsf-2.2, http-request-parameters, flow-scope

I tried the last version of JavaServer Faces 2.2 (Mojarra 2.2.4) 
and noticed changing my query string in this unwanted way:

```
page.jsf?jftfdi=&jffi=
```

instead of

```
page.jsf
```

I've found that it is the new JSF 2.2 feature. But these query params(jftfdi, jffi) spoil me SEO-friendly urls. How can I disable it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17594856/what-are-jftfdi-jffi-doing-to-my-query-string

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a bug in Mojarra. They should not have been appended when there's no means of any flow navigation configuration ([by the new `@FlowScoped` annotation and `<j:flow-xxx>` tags](http://jdevelopment.nl/jsf-22/#730)).

Basically, the `OutcomeTargetRenderer` class who's responsible for HTML output generation of the `<h:link>` and `<h:button>` is incorrectly checking if [`NavigationCase#getToFlowDocumentId()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/faces/application/NavigationCase.html#getToFlowDocumentId%28%29) returns non-`null` before appending the flow navigation parameters. However, based on [the javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/faces/application/NavigationCase.html#getToFlowDocumentId%28%29) the base implementation never returns `null`, but an empty string. Therefore, the renderer always thinks that it's in middle of a flow navigation and always appends the associated `jftfdi` and `jffi` request parameters. The fix is to let it check as well if it returns a non-empty string.

I reported it as [issue 3054](https://java.net/jira/browse/JAVASERVERFACES-3054) and they confirmed that this is a bug and are currently working on it. The fix will likely be available in Mojarra 2.2.5.

**Update**: as of now, less than a day later, it's fixed for 2.2.5.

---

By the way, the [`jftfdi`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/faces/flow/FlowHandler.html#TO_FLOW_DOCUMENT_ID_REQUEST_PARAM_NAME) stands for "`javax.faces` To Flow Document ID" which is specified as follows in [the javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/faces/flow/FlowHandler.html#TO_FLOW_DOCUMENT_ID_REQUEST_PARAM_NAME):

> Components that are rendered by Renderers of component-family `javax.faces.OutcomeTarget` must use this constant as the parameter name for a parameter representing the defining document id of the flow that this component will cause to be entered.

and the [`jffi`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/faces/flow/FlowHandler.html#FLOW_ID_REQUEST_PARAM_NAME) stands for "`javax.faces` Flow ID" which is specified as follows in [the javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/faces/flow/FlowHandler.html#FLOW_ID_REQUEST_PARAM_NAME):

> Components that are rendered by Renderers of component-family `javax.faces.OutcomeTarget` must use this constant as the parameter name for a parameter representing the flow id of the flow that this component will cause to be entered.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same error before. The origin of this bug is the version of jsf. 
Just try to upgrade version to 2.2.5 like this :

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsf-impl</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.5</version>
    </dependency>
```

Hope it's helpfull

Comment: This is already in the upvoted and accepted answer: **"Update: as of now, less than a day later, it's fixed for 2.2.5."** So this answer add nothing to the question. Can you elaborate why you think this answer should be there?