# <h:button> not executing simple bean method

Tags: jsf, button

im trying to do a simple bean method, but it does not work, dont show the syso in the console of eclispe, and when i click the button, it change my url to `http://localhost:8080/Projeto01/index.jsf?jftfdi=&jffi=%2Findex.xhtml`

why dont work and why it change the url for this strange url ?

my msg.java(bean)

```
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;

    @ManagedBean
    @SessionScoped
    public class Msg {

        public void show() {
            System.out.println("Working Bean Method");
        }
    }
```

my index.xhtml

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">
        <ui:composition>

<h:head></h:head>

    <h:body>
    <h:form>

    <h:button value="Show" action="#{msg.show()}"></h:button>

    </h:form>
    </h:body>
    </ui:composition>
</html>
```

and my web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" version="2.5">
  <display-name>do0</display-name>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `<h:button>` is a simple page-to-page navigation button. As you can see in the [tag documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/javaserverfaces/2.2/vdldocs/facelets/h/button.html), it doesn't support the `action` attribute at all. You're most likely confusing the `<h:button>` with `<h:commandButton>` which in turn supports that attribute.

In order to achieve your functional requirement of invoking a JSF backing bean method on press of a button, just replace `<h:button>` by `<h:commandButton>`:

```
<h:commandButton value="Show" action="#{msg.show()}" />
```

#### See also:

- [Difference between h:button and h:commandButton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13070537/difference-between-hbutton-and-hcommandbutton)

---

As to those `jftfdi` and `jffi` query string parameters in the target URL, this is a bug in Mojarra's implementation of the new JSF 2.2 flow scope. This is fixed in Mojarra 2.2.5. Note that this is further unrelated to your concrete problem as you shouldn't be using a `<h:button>` in first place.

#### See also:

- [How to disable jftfdi jffi query params in JSF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19255367/how-to-disable-jftfdi-jffi-query-params-in-jsf/19260462#19260462)