# How to update to the latest version of Mojarra at IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate

Tags: intellij-idea, tomcat7, jsf-2.2, mojarra

At my Java Web Project using IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate 13.1, there is Mojarra-2.2.1.

After seeing the jftfdi parameters being appended to a link (without me using flows) I've found [this reply by BalusC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19255367/how-to-disable-jftfdi-jffi-query-params-in-jsf), and saw that this is a bug that was fixed in version 2.2.5.
So I now need to update the version of Mojarra.

**What I've tried:**

1. So I've deleted Mojarra-2.2.1 and then installed (from Maven again), the library `javax.faces-2.2.8.jar` which resulted in a *The resource was not found* error from Tomcat. I have now re-enabled Mojarra-2.2.1 by opening Project Settings > Modules > Clicking on the module name > Dependencies > "+" and then selecting Mojarra 2.2.1 from the global libraries.
2. Opening Project Settings > Global Libraries > Selecting Mojarra-2.2.1 and then clicking Change Version..., but the only options are the current, Mojarra-2.0.1-FCS and Mojarra-1.2.

I am using Tomcat 7, with IntelliJ Ultimate 13.1.

What can I do?