# Pretty Faces creates URLs with jffi and jftdi request params

Tags: jsf, prettyfaces

I'm using Pretty Faces in combination with Spring, Spring Security and JSF. My problem is, that I'm getting get a weird url string, when I click a link which is declared like this:

```
<h:link outcome="pretty:imprint">Imprint</h:link>
```

**Weird String:**
    http://localhost:8080/MyWebApp/Imprint;jsessionid=69D420639A9ED0C1BA39F0980F6A3E25?jffi=%2Fimprint.xhtml%3Fcom.ocpsoft.mappingId%3Dimprint&jftfdi=

**pretty-config.xml**

```
<pretty-config xmlns="http://ocpsoft.com/prettyfaces/3.3.0" 
           xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
           xsi:schemaLocation="http://ocpsoft.com/prettyfaces/3.3.0
           http://ocpsoft.com/xml/ns/prettyfaces/ocpsoft-pretty-faces-3.3.0.xsd">

  <url-mapping id="imprint"> 
      <pattern value="/Imprint" /> 
      <view-id value="/imprint.xhtml" />
  </url-mapping>
</pretty-config>
```

But when I follow the link without the strange additional string (http://localhost:8080/MyWebApp/Imprint) I'm also directed to the right page.

Does anyone have an idea, where this string comes from?

Comment: Searchengines help. 'jsf jffi param' resulted in at least this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19255367/how-to-disable-jftfdi-jffi-query-params-in-jsf and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17594856/what-are-jftfdi-jffi-doing-to-my-query-string

Comment: And even on the prettyfaces site: http://www.ocpsoft.org/support/topic/startup-with-prettyfaces/ so make searchengines your friend

Comment: Thank you, I searched for pretty faces and not for jffy, that was the problem. Pretty tough title! ;)